# Converting from an int to a bool in C#

Tags: c#

```
int vote;

Insertvotes(objectType, objectId , vote, userID); //calling
```

For this method call, I want to convert `vote` to a `bool`. How can I convert it?

Here is the method signature:

```
 public static bool Insertvotes(int forumObjectType, 
                                int objectId,
                                bool isThumbUp, 
                                int userID) 
{
    // code...
}
```

Comment: please refrain from using ALL CAPS in question title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try something like

```
Insertvotes(objectType, objectId , (vote == 1), userID); //calling
```

Assuming that 1 is voted up, and 0 is voted down, or something like that.

Comment: That could be the case, but I think that the check will be purely based on the business rule to be applied.

Answer (score 5):

To go from int to boolean

```
bool isThumbsUp = Convert.ToBoolean(1); //Will give you isThumbsUp == true
```

To go from boolean to int

```
int isThumbsUp = Convert.ToInt32(false); //Will give you isThumbsUp == 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it depend upon semantics of your program. What does isThumbUp indicate? A business rule may say that if there is one vote (i.e. vote > 0) then its thumbs up or it may say that if there are minimum 5 votes (vote >= 5) then only its "thumbs up". So based on that your call will change - but it would be something like

```
Insertvotes(objectType, objectId , (vote > [n]), userID);
```

n being the number of votes needed for thumbs up.

Answer (score 3):

If votes are true if they are greater than zero then you convert them to bool this way:

```
Insertvotes(objectType, objectId , vote > 0, userID);
```